# How to return data or object in function depending on the context in which it is called?

Tags: javascript

I have an object that is constructed with serveral arguments like this:

```
var foo = myFunc(arg1).a(arg2).b(arg3)
```

I'd like to be able to return either the function object or just a scaler depending on how the function is called.

```
var foo = myFunc(arg1).a(arg2).b(arg3) // return an object
var bar = myFunc(arg1)                 // return a scaler value
```

Here's my function:

```
var myFunc = function(value) {

  var a, b

  f = function(value) { return value }

  f.a = function(fn) { 
    a = fn(value)
    return this;
  }

  f.b = function(fn) { 
    b = fn(value)
    return this;
  }

  return f
}

var foo = myFunc(10)
  .a(function(d) { return d * 10 })  
  .b(function(d) { return d * 100 })  

// returns 10
foo.a(function(d) { console.log(d) }) 

// returns: { [Function] a: [Function], b: [Function] }
console.log(myFunc(10))  //  <<< how can i make this return 10?
```

I'd like to have my function return 10 when called without methods and return an object when called with methods. How can I do this?

Comment: That's quite impossible. You can't know what happens to your return value from inside the function.

Comment: However, you can do a lot of magic by returning an object that has a  `.valueOf` method. See the duplicate question, especially my second (non-accepted) answer.